# getting null value for expired at date

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

This is my entity class:

```
namespace Bits\JobBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Bits\JobBundle\Utils\Jobeet as Jobeet;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Job
 * 
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bits\JobBundle\Entity\JobRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */


class Job
{

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="expires_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $expires_at;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updated_at;

    /**
     * @var \Bits\JobBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * Set expires_at
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @param \DateTime $expires_at
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setExpiresAt()
    {
        $this->expires_at=new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get expires_at
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getExpiresAt()
    {
        return $this->expires_at;
    }
```

Job.orm.yml

```
Bits\JobBundle\Entity\Job:
    type: entity
    table: job
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: {strategy: auto}
    fields:
        type:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        expires_at:
            type: datetime
        created_at:
            type: datetime
        updated_at:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
    manyToOne:
        category:
            targetEntity: Category
            inversedBy: jobs
            joinColumn:
                name: category_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    lifeCycleCallbacks:
        prePersist: [setCreatedAt, setExpiresAt]
        preUpdate: [setUpdatedAt]
```

I am getting null value in expires_at value.

This is the SQL error.

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO job (type, company, logo, url, position, location, description, how_to_apply, token, is_public, is_activated, email, expires_at, created_at, updated_at, category_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "test", null, null, "test", "test", "test", "test", "sdfa", 0, null, "asdf", null, null, null, null]:

How to debug ?

Comment: Can you give more details ? How do you fill the job entity ?

Comment: The problem is not with filling the form. The expired at value will  automatically generated. But, in my case it has not generated. When I echo something on setExpiresAt function, this function is not called while insert operation. This means I get the above SQL statement

Comment: @SudinManandhar post the code you are using to persist the entity

Comment: I have added the orm.yml file

Comment: why do you have 2 mappings for the same entity!!

Answer (score 0):

add method like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setExpiresAtCreate()
{
    if ($this->expires_at === null)
        $this->expires_at = new \DateTime('2222-12-22');
}
```

And change lifecycleCallbacks like that:

```
lifeCycleCallbacks:
        prePersist: [setCreatedAtCreate, setExpiresAtCreate]
        preUpdate: [setUpdatedAtUpdate]
```

Please try not name lifecycleCallbacks named like settes, it's bad practise

Answer (score 0):

add to PrePersist ()

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function setExpiresAtCreate()
{
    if ($this->expires_at === null)
        $this->expires_at = new \DateTime('2222-12-22');
}
```

or

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->expires_at = new \DateTime('2222-12-22');
}
```